# Launching Wolfram Engine from MacOS Monterey Shortcuts app

Tags: warning-messages, free-wolfram-engine

I am trying to figure out how to launch the Wolfram Engine from the Shortcuts app (new feature app in MacOS Monterey). Usually, I open the terminal go to the directory where I store my notebooks and launch the WE from this directory by typing in terminal window:

```
cd $HOME/wolframjupyter
jupyter notebook
```

So, I copied this into MacOS Shortcuts app and try to run it to launch the WE, however it produces an error which I don't understand (attached image below)

[image]

Can anyone help to fix the error? Thanks

Comment: Open the shortcuts app.  Click plus.  Select scripting.  Drag “Open App” to main window.  Click App.  Selected the program to open.

Comment: thanks, but there is no app "Jupyter notebook" app to click in my machine. Any alternative?

Comment: Is it a question of providing the full path to the jupyter app? The Shortcut app’s context may not have access to the $PATH of your usual terminal window

Comment: No, not the path. The issue was that the Shotcut app didn't have permission to run scripts, I solved this by going to Preferences, Advanced and Allow Running Scripts